# How to enforce DirectX9 instead of DirectX11

Tags: directx, directx-9

My feature levels are

```
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] = 
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3
};
```

and create device calls is the following

```
D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, driverTypes[i], NULL, 
                              createDeviceFlags, featureLevels, numFeatureLevels, 
                              D3D11_SDK_VERSION, 
                              &swapDesc, &m_pSwapChain, &m_pDevice, 
                              &m_FeatureLevel, &m_pImmediateContext);
```

So how can i make it run in DirectX 9 forcefully.

`D3D11_SDK_VERSION` is a `UINT`, what should it be for `D3D9` as just changing the feature level doesn't do the job?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here exactly? As long as you are calling ``D3D11CreateDevice``, you are using the DirectX 11 Runtime. There's a distinct axis of what Direct3D hardware feature levels you support. The ``D3D11_SDK_VERSION`` flag has nothing to do with the OS or hardware support; it just ensures that you are using supported C++ headers with the runtime which was a problem back in the legacy DirectX SDK era that was just carried forward. Direct3D 12 device creation doesn't have such a parameter.

Comment: Note that you really at a minimum need to list ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3`` and ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0`` to get broad hardware support without always paying a performance penalty for 9.x feature emulation on newer hardware. Also, all your shaders are actually built for both Shader Model 2.x and Shader Model 4.0 when you use the ``?s_4_0_level_9_3`` profiles, so by using just ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3`` you are never getting the benefit of the better codegen of Shader Model 4.0.

Comment: Actually i have an application in C# that is using sharpDX library to do the graphics part but MSI afterburner is detecting that its running on D3D9 even though specifically D3D11 was specified and also the OSD(On screen display of FPS e.t.c) was also not showing. 

So to check things up i tried to create an application in C++ and tried to force it to use D3D9. After reading your comments I feel stupid in using the D3D11 library to start D3D9 engine. The part that was confusing me was that you could specify `featureLevels` and `D3D11_SDK_VERSION`.